# Angular Routing Error: "ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges"

Tags: angular, routes

the component searchs for data in a list depends on the url, If the data is not found it redirects the user to a 404 page, everything works fine and the user can't notice any difference but I get this error on the console
[image]

### Redirect code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.index = +params.get("index"); // Get the index of the palette from the link
      this.palette = this.colorsServices.getPalette(this.index);
      if (typeof this.palette == 'undefined') { // If the palette not exist
        this.router.navigate(["/not-found"]); 
      }
    });
  }
```

### Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: CardsComponent},
  {path: 'palette/:index', component: PaletteComponent},
  {path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent},
  {path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent}
];
```

Comment: Are you invoking the detectChanges() function somewhere ?

Comment: No, I don't use it.